# DynamoDB DAX errors: ValidationException while testing lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I am trying to run DAX sample getitem-test.js as a lambda.([doc link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.client.run-application-nodejs.03-getitem-test.html)).I modified code to read from daxclient which I created. But daxClient.get returns error from lambda

> START RequestId: bb657a02-05b1-11e8-804d-a1d27ac0e9f7 Version: $LATEST
>   2018-01-30T11:36:03.363Z    bb657a02-05b1-11e8-804d-a1d27ac0e9f7    Unable to read item. Error JSON: {
>     "time": 1517312163361,
>     "code": "ValidationException",
>     "retryable": true,
>     "requestId": "AVI5QK8LN9S41B64JTTJVECLR3VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
>     "statusCode": "400",
>     "_tubeInvalid": false,
>     "waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying": false
>   }

I have setup dynamo db tables using dynamodbclient. setup VPC, subnets etc.. But I have no luck reading data from DAX. Any idea what could be the issue.

Following is the code I used:

```
var region = "eu-west-1";
AWS.config.update({
    region: region
});
var daxClient = null;
var dax = new AmazonDaxClient({ endpoints: ["mydax.e02jim.clustercfg.dax.euw1.cache.amazonaws.com:8111"], region: region })
daxClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ service: dax });
var tableName = "TryDaxTable";
var params = {
    TableName: tableName,
    Key: {
        "pk": 7,
        "sk": 1
    }
};
daxClient.get(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", 
JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("success");
    }
});
```

I can get the result using `var ddbClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()`
instead of `daxClient`.

Also my lambda function is timed out

Comment: Can you share the exact code you are using? ValidationException usually means that the request is incorrect in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that it was a permission issue. IAM role for my cluster did not have permission to DynamoDB table.

Regarding lambda timeout I added following code in the end after googling

```
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false
callback(null, "success");
```